# How to combine type alias with the definition of full specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, type-alias

I can combine type alias with class definition like this:

```
using XX = struct AA { };
```

But how can I combine type alias with the definition of a **full** specialization?

```
template < typename... > struct BB;

using YY = template <> struct BB<int> { }; // error: expected type-specifier before ‘template’
```

Is there a nice workaround that would allow to escape a separate line `using YY = BB<int>;` after the definition of `BB<int>`?

Comment: What's wrong with the separate line?

Comment: @Barry I missed that the separate line can actually be **before** the definition of specialization. So by placing it before I achieved what I wanted. It is a macro like this: `DEFINE_OBJECT(name) using name = BB<name>; template <> struct BB<name>`